# Nested groups in Angular2 forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm using the reactive forms module in Angular 2 to create a form with several nested groups.

My 'trust' form has an array of contacts at

```
<FormArray>this.newTrustForm.controls['contact']
```

One of the fields in the 'contact' group is an array of 'email' groups and I tried finding it here, but alas, no. Where would I then find it?

```
<FormArray>this.newTrustForm.controls['contact'].controls['email']
```

I setup my form with the following.

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.newTrustForm = this._fb.group({
    ...
    contact: this._fb.array([]),
    ...
  });
}
```

I then add 'contact' groups with the following.

```
initContact() {
  return this._fb.group({
    ...
    email: this._fb.array([]),
    ...
  });
}
```

And then I have initContactEmail setup in the same way.

Comment: you should show us how you are creating these groups.

Comment: @Fals See edits. TIA.

Comment: I'm not seeing you iterating through every contact to create the email group. if you're are nesting, you should do this. Take a look at the last example from the oficial site: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#form-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specify the index of `contact`:

```
<FormArray>this.newTrustForm.controls['contact'][INDEX]['controls']['email']
```

Or (more readable):

```
this.newTrustForm.get(`contact.${INDEX}.email`) as FormArray;
```

Also, as a suggestion, since `contact` and `email` are `arrays`, you could named them in plural: `contacts` and `emails`.