# Nested arrays in Angular 2 reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have use the following tutorial to create reactive forms in Angular 2 and it works well.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

However, I am now trying to add an array within an array. Using the tutorial above, I have created an 'Organisation' form, which can contain an array of 'Contact' groups. But I am unable to successfully adapt the setup to allow each 'Contact' group to contain an array of 'Email' groups.

I have been unable to find a tutorial or example that covers this and would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Add your code here or create fiddle so that we can see.

Comment: You asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42558329/4911842

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested groups in Angular2 forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558329/nested-groups-in-angular2-forms)

Comment: @developer033 I asked part of the question there, yes and got an answer, but I still can't put the whole thing together in a working form.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Using the tutorial above, I have created an 'Organisation' form, which
>   can contain an array of 'Contact' groups. But I am unable to
>   successfully adapt the setup to allow each 'Contact' group to contain
>   an array of 'Email' groups.

The tutorial above gives you all what you need.

I suppose you want structure like this.

[image]

Firstly you need some component (`AppComponent` in my case) where you declare root `FormGroup`. I called it `trustForm` below.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  trustForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trustForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      contracts: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.addContract();
  }

  initContract() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      emails: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  addContract() {
    const contractArray = <FormArray>this.trustForm.controls['contracts'];
    const newContract = this.initContract();

    contractArray.push(newContract);
  }

  removeContract(idx: number) {
    const contractsArray = <FormArray>this.trustForm.controls['contracts'];
    contractsArray.removeAt(idx);
  }
}
```

In this component you have also some methods that help you to manipulate the first level `FormArray` - `contracts`

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="trustForm">
        <h3>Add trust</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
        </div>

        <!--contracts-->
        <div formArrayName="contracts">
            <div *ngFor="let contract of trustForm.controls.contracts.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span>Contract {{i + 1}}</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="trustForm.controls.contracts.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeContract(i)"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <contract [group]="trustForm.controls.contracts.controls[i]"></contract>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-20">
            <button (click)="addContract()" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add another contract +
            </button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <h5>Details</h5>
    <pre>{{ trustForm.value | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

There is no different from root html from the tutorial except different `FormArray` name.

Then you need to build contract component that will be similar to `AppComponent`

**contract.component.ts**

```
export class ContractComponent {
    @Input('group') contractGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    addEmail() {
        const emailArray = <FormArray>this.contractGroup.controls['emails'];
        const newEmail = this.initEmail();

        emailArray.push(newEmail);
    }

    removeEmail(idx: number) {
        const emailArray = <FormArray>this.contractGroup.controls['emails'];
        emailArray.removeAt(idx);
    }

    initEmail() {
        return this.fb.group({
            text: ''
        });
    }
}
```

**contract.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="contractGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </div>

    <!--emails-->
    <div formArrayName="emails">
        <div *ngFor="let email of contractGroup.controls.emails.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span>Email {{i + 1}}</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="contractGroup.controls.emails.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeEmail(i)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                <email [group]="contractGroup.controls.emails.controls[i]"></email>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-20">
        <button (click)="addEmail()" class="btn btn-primary">
            Add another email +
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see we just replace `contracts` to `emails` `FormArray` and we are also passing `FormGroup` to email component

And finally you will only need to fill `EmailComponent` with desired fields.

**email.component.ts**

```
export class EmailComponent {
    @Input('group') emailGroup: FormGroup;
}
```

**email.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="emailGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Text</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Completed version you can find at **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vSODkb8i7o54X3fST9VF?p=preview)**

If you think that this solution doesn't seems right because the parent component holds the description of the child component like `initContract` and `initEmails` you can take a look at more complex

### [Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/azWpaFNC0ItsOcGj6sAK?p=preview)

where each component is responsible for its functionality.

If you're looking for solution for template driven forms read this article:

- [Angular: Nested template driven form](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)

Comment: I have similar requirment for my concept as you answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205237/how-to-build-nested-array-by-using-angular2-reactive-forms , but you map form group . Actually my values are building first in '.ts' file and through '.ts' file i am repeating value in form group by using ng-for.My html form should be as mention in quesion.Please help me out from this situation.

Comment: In this post your building new form, like this I want to build form forexisting array

Comment: I'm sorry it's taken me a long time to acknowledge this, but it's exactly what I needed. Makes a lot of sense once you've seen it done :) Thank you!