# How to build nested array by using angular2 Reactive forms?

Tags: json, angular, multidimensional-array, angular2-template, angular2-forms

```
I have an array like 
[  
   {  
      "PermissionRoleModule":{  
         "id":1,
         "legend":"businessModule",
         "group":[  
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"create Business"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"edit business"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "PermissionRoleModule":{  
         "id":2,
         "legend":"PanicModule",
         "group":[  
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"create panic"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"edit panic"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

and my view is like shown in attatchment [image]

when I click submit button I am expecting json like

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "description":"das",
      "permission":[  
         {  
            "permission_id":1,
            "relation":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How to build form group for this case using reactive forms

I tried like this

**component.ts**

```
roleForm: FormGroup;
  formField: any;
validateForm() {
this.formField['rolename'] = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
this.formField['roledescription'] = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]))

this.form_objects.forEach(element => {
  if (element.group) {
    element.group.forEach(PermissionRoleGroup => {
      this.formField[PermissionRoleGroup.permission.key] = new FormControl({value:''}, Validators.compose([Validators.required]))

      if (PermissionRoleGroup.roles) {
        PermissionRoleGroup.roles.forEach(role => {
          this.formField[role.key] = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
        });
      }

    })
  }
});

this.roleForm = this.fb.group(this.formField);
 }
```

**html**

```
   <div  class="form-row" *ngFor="let element of form_objects; let i = index; ">

              <table  class="table table-bordered">
                <tr *ngFor="let permissionRoleGroup of element.group;let j= index;">
                  <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    <td width="40%">
                      <label class="font-light">
                        <input type="checkbox"

                               [id]="permissionRoleGroup.permission.key"
                               [formControlName]="permissionRoleGroup.permission.key"
                               [value] = "permissionRoleGroup.permission.value">
                        {{permissionRoleGroup.permission.label }}-{{permissionRoleGroup.permission.ischecked}}
                      </label>
                    </td>

                    <td width="15%" *ngFor="let role of permissionRoleGroup.roles">
                      <label class="font-light">
                        <input   type="checkbox"

                                 [value] = "role.value"
                                 [formControlName]=" role.key">
                        {{role.label}}-{{role.ischecked}}
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  </table>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </div>
```

with this I am able to build form , during submission, my form is not creating json .

This is plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/h2VuBw4uITi6czn98ViS?p=preview

As i am beginner in angular-2 so  please help me out.

Comment: Can you share template?

Comment: I added html code , Please check it

Comment: How do you fill `form_objects`? Would be great if you provided plunker

Comment: i added plunk link can u please check it

Comment: Even I have similar issue, It would be better to us if anyone can provide better approach

Comment: @yuzui  I have a concept like **"other"**  as i mentioned before in my question . for the other i have one more json section which should come like :   {  
   "roleName":"dfd",
   "roleDescription":"dfdf",
   "permissions":[  
      {  
         "permission_id":2,
         "relation":1,
         "otherrole":[  
            {  
               "roleid":2,
               "status":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

Comment: check this link., it's help to solve out your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291346/how-to-iterate-form-arrayarray-in-array-in-array-in-angular2-reactive-forms

Comment: Thank you @soumya Gangamwar, That's what I am exacly looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create some property like `permissionGroups` and flatten your data

```
permissionGroups: any[];
...
this.permissionGroups = this.form_objects
   .reduce((acc, permission) => [...acc, ...permission.group], []);
```

then i would build `formGroup` like this:

```
const permissions = this.permissionGroups.map(group => {
  return this.fb.group({
    [group.permission.key]: false,
    roles: this.fb.array(group.roles.map(role => this.fb.control(false)))
  });
});

this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
  roleName: ['', Validators.required],
  roleDescription: ['', Validators.required],
  permissions: this.fb.array(permissions)
});
```

and prepare html as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="roleForm" (submit)="submit(roleForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="roleName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" formControlName="roleDescription"></textarea>
    </div>          

    <div formArrayName="permissions">
      <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let permission of roleForm.controls.permissions.controls; let i = index; ">
         <table [formArrayName]="i">
            <tr>
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label class="font-light">
                        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="permissionGroups[i].permission.key">
                        {{ permissionGroups[i].permission.key }}
                      </label>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngFor="let role of permission.controls.roles.controls; let j = index;">
                      <label class="font-light" formArrayName="roles">
                        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="j">    
                        {{ permissionGroups[i].roles[j].name }}         
                      </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And when you will submit the form you need to convert form value to your desired result something like this:

```
submit(value) {
  this.result = Object.assign({}, value, {
    permissions: value.permissions
      .reduce((acc, permission, idx) => {
        return permission[this.permissionGroups[idx].permission.key] ?
          [
            ...acc,
            {
              permission_id: this.permissionGroups[idx].permission.id,
              relation: permission.roles
                .reduce((rolesAcc, role, roleIdx) => {
                  return role ? [...rolesAcc, this.permissionGroups[idx].roles[roleIdx].id] : rolesAcc;
                }, [])
            }
          ] : acc
      }, [])
  });
}
```

and you will see the output like:

```
{
  "roleName": "",
  "roleDescription": "",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission_id": 2,
      "relation": [
        1
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission_id": 2,
      "relation": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can play with the code in **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nSHvlPfQXJZhucNrezz9?p=preview)**

See also

- https://netbasal.com/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-angular-forms-57eb8e846d21

Comment: @yuzui Thank you So much,

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Ok, what is mean of [...rolesAcc in above code, (...)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: @yuzui I have a concept like "other" as i mentioned before in my question . for the other i have one more json section which should come like : { "roleName":"dfd", "roleDescription":"dfdf", "permissions":[ { "permission_id":2, "relation":1, "otherrole":[ { "roleid":2, "status":1 } ] } ] }

Comment: Add it to my plunker. I don't completely understand your structure.

Comment: In submit form I need to send data like { "roleName":"dfd", "roleDescription":"dfdf", "permissions":[ { "permission_id":2, "relation":1, "otherrole":[ { "roleid":2, "status":1 } ] } ] }  if role is other , otherwise no need to send "otherrole" to backend

Comment: @yuzui I modified plunker, please check it

Comment: I have similar issue, In your solution ur mappnig array as required, but after mapping user want to  send any values from html to ts on onchange permission, roles function( like base element, permissiongroup), how it's possible ,

Comment: @yurzui can you please take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250978/how-to-validate-matrix-of-inputs

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following function:

```
patchValue(form:any, object:any){

    var iterate = (mForm:any, mObject:any)=> {
        for (var key in mObject) {
            if (Array.isArray(mObject[key])) {
                if(mForm.value[key] == undefined || mForm.value[key] == null){
                    if(Array.isArray(mForm.value)){
                        mForm.push(new FormArray([]));
                    } else {
                        mForm.addControl(key, new FormArray([]));
                    }
                }
                iterate(mForm.controls[key], mObject[key]);
            }
            else if (typeof mObject[key] == 'string' || typeof mObject[key] == 'number' || typeof mObject[key] == 'boolean' || mObject[key] == null) {
                if(mForm.value[key] == undefined || mForm.value[key] == null){
                    if(Array.isArray(mForm.value)){
                        mForm.push(new FormControl(''));
                    } else {
                        mForm.addControl(key, new FormControl(''));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (mObject[key] != null && typeof mObject[key] == 'object') {
                if(mForm.value[key] == undefined || mForm.value[key] == null){
                    if(Array.isArray(mForm.value)){
                        mForm.push(new FormGroup({}));
                    } else {
                        mForm.addControl(key, new FormGroup({}));
                    }
                }

                iterate(mForm.controls[key], mObject[key]);
            }
            else {
                console.log(key);
                console.log('undefined element');
            }
        }
    };

    iterate(form, object);

    form.patchValue(object);
}
```

Simply pass an empty form and your object. It will build your form based on the object you passed:

```
this.form = this.fb.array([]);
this.template = [  
   {  
      "PermissionRoleModule":{  
         "id":1,
         "legend":"businessModule",
         "group":[  
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"create Business"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"edit business"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "PermissionRoleModule":{  
         "id":2,
         "legend":"PanicModule",
         "group":[  
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"create panic"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "PermissionRoleGroup":{  
                  "id":1,
                  "permission":{  
                     "controleType":"ff",
                     "id":2,
                     "key":"edit panic"
                  },
                  "roles":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"self"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"other"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
this.patchValue(this.form, this.template);
```

If you want to build it yourself, you have to do it manually... I would recommend you this article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks , But it would be better for me if u add this in plunker , I added one plunk link above  , Can u please modified with your solution,

Comment: @ncohen Can you provide html

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar The html depends on your template

Comment: ya, I mean to say that any plunker example for above comment code, with that i can understood properly