# How to display data from array "Products": [{}]

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

How to populate this JSON in my EditForm. I have EditForm, that I want to display my data, my ws get me this JSON. My data outside `Products` I can display in html, but data inside Products I don't know why not display. What is the problem?

This is my Json

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "Products": [
                {
                    "p_id": "11E8218A54B30C89AE8800FF76874A59",
                    "p_pt_id": "11E7FC041F467AD4B09D00FF76874A59",
                    "p_l": 233,
                    "p_d": "test",
                    "p_q": 4,
                    "p_u_p": 50,
                    "p_s": 120                  
                }
            ],
            "sale_item_id": "11E8219D916A69F6AE8800FF76874A59",
            "sale_id": "11E8218B9BA4F278AE8800FF76874A59",
            "client_id": "11E8218A57B28B0AAE8800FF76874A59",
            "sale_date": "2018-03-06T22:09:43.000Z",
            "notes": "testing",
            "subtotal": 80,
            "total": 50,
            "invoice_number": "28282",
            "invoice_date": "2018-03-06T21:57:41.000Z",
            "amount_paid": 32       
        }
    ]
}
```

My ts code.

```
editForm: FormGroup;    

    this.editForm = this.fb.group({

      'sale_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'sale_date': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
       'p_d': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'p_pt_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
         'p_l': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': new FormControl([])
    });

  populateForm() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ws.salegetbyid(params['id']).subscribe(
          sale => {
            this.sale = sale;
            this.editForm.controls['sale_id'].setValue(sale.sale_id);
            this.editForm.controls['client_id'].setValue(sale.client_id);
            this.editForm.controls['sale_date'].setValue(sale.sale_date);
            this.editForm.controls['notes'].setValue(sale.notes);
            this.editForm.controls['total'].setValue(sale.total);
              this.editForm.patchValue({
              p_pt_id: this.sale.products.map(x => x.p_pt_id),
              p_l: this.sale.products.map(x => x.p_l),
                 p_d: this.sale.products.map(x => x.p_d)
            })
           }
        );

      }
    );
  }
```

And my html code

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="oneddit()" class="col s12" materialize>

  <div class="contant">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        sale_id:
        <input formControlName="sale_id" id="sale_id" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        client_id:
        <input formControlName="client_id" id="client_id" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        sale_date:
        <input formControlName="sale_date" id="sale_date" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        notes:
        <input formControlName="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        total:
        <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="number" class="validate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <thead>
      <tr style="color:black;">
        <th>p_d</th>
        <th>p_pt_id</th>
        <th>p_l</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products;">
        <td>{{item.p_d}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_pt_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_l}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>

  <div class="row" style="float: right;">
    <button id="add_client_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
      Register
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I change this code, like

ts code:

```
'products': this.fb.array([])

 this.sale.products.forEach(x => {
          (this.editForm.get('products') as FormArray).push(new FormControl(x.products))
        })
```

and in html:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of editForm.get('products').value; let i = index">
        <td>{{item.p_d}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_pt_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_l}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

but this change show me this error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'item.p_d' of null at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Can you help me, what is the problem?

Comment: you haven't put the formControlName for that

Comment: @Lonna You have not mapped your `json` that good as a `formGroup`. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291346/how-to-iterate-form-arrayarray-in-array-in-array-in-angular2-reactive-forms

Comment: @Thodoris I make some change, look my comment please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put in your `html` `{{editForm.value | json}}` to see what you have in there.

Second I suppose that `this.sale.products` refers to `StatusDescription`. Now `products` is an array of let us say `product` objects.
You ask `products` for `product` attributes. So supposing that you map your object correctly, you would need `editForm.get('products').value` in `html`. Form arrays are arrays of `FormGroup` that they in turn have `FormControl`

Try this:

```
     this.sale.products.forEach(x => {
              (this.editForm.get('products') as FormArray).push(new FormGroup({
           p_id: x.p_id,
           p_l: x.p_l // and so on
         }))
     })
```

Comment: Hello, when I put in html {{editForm.value | json}} my Json display. When I put  in ts, your code and in html this editForm.get('products.0.p_id').value nothing change.

Comment: @Lonna Does the json display include the array of products with the first product already mapped? If yes `ngFor` iterates arrays not objects so this could be your display problem.

Comment: Really thank you  Thodoris , I have shown below how to solved this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, like this

```
this.sale.products.forEach(product => {
    (this.editForm.get('products') as FormArray).push(this.createFGPoduct(product))
})

    createFGPoduct(product: Product): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({
           p_id: new FormControl(product.p_id),
           p_pt_id: new FormControl(product.p_pt_id, [Validators.required]),
           p_l: new FormControl(product.p_l, [Validators.required]),
           p_d: new FormControl(product.p_d, [Validators.required])

        })
    }
```

HTML code.

```
 <tbody>
      <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of editForm.get('products').value; let i = index">
        <td>{{item.p_d}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_pt_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_l}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Add this as an update in the Question, not in the answer section.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19036778)

Comment: @AleksAndreev I change it :) thnx