# How to create nested model driven forms in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a form with 2 fields, 1 of it is an array. I would like to make this whole form as a array, when i click Add question, it will dynamically have another 2 fields like this.

**Add Question 1** - All fields are mandatory  (Add question)
Ask your question *
Answer 1 *

**Add Question 2** - All fields are mandatory
Ask your question *
Answer 1 *

Another Answer

I've tried but failed. Please kindly help. Thank you. below is the code in StackBlitz.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j92gcm?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: `I've tried but failed` Please elaborate what is the error are you getting?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/clTbNP7MHBbBbrUp20vr?p=preview this should be helpful :)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783400/nested-arrays-in-angular-2-reactive-forms

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth thanks i will try it. Any idea how does the app.component uses the contract.component? I don't see any routing or import.

Comment: I did not understand. what you are trying to convey.

Comment: As in to use a component in another component, usually there is a <app-router> or importing in the. ts file. However i dont see any of it. So how does app.component use contract.component. Referring to the link you gave.

Comment: @yurzui how can i add validation since its in a different omponent for your plunker example. https://plnkr.co/edit/vSODkb8i7o54X3fST9VF?p=preview