# ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: html, angular

It throws me this error in console, however the form is working right whenever I clic.

Seriously, I don't see the mistake, I have another template with the same syntax and it doesn't throw me this error

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
              <h4 class="title">Comparativa mensual</h4>
              <p class="category">Año actual</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <app-pie-graph #graphmonths></app-pie-graph>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="formGroup">
              <form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="submit($event)">
                <h4 class="title inline">Comparativa diaria</h4>
                <my-date-range-picker  name="mydaterange"  [options]="myOptions" formControlName="myDateRange"></my-date-range-picker>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <p class="category">Vista de una semana</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <app-pie-graph #graphdays></app-pie-graph>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Error

```
ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

UPDATE: ts file------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { LinearGraphComponent } from '../../shared/graph/linear-graph/linear-graph.component';
import { PieGraphComponent } from '../../shared/graph/pie-graph/pie-graph.component';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { Data } from '../data';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.css']
})
export class OverviewComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

  @ViewChild('graphdays') private pieGraphDays: PieGraphComponent;
  @ViewChild('graphmonths') private pieGraphMonths: PieGraphComponent;
  @ViewChild('generaloverview') private linearGraph: LinearGraphComponent;

  //COMMON
  public getDataRetriever(): Data { return this.dataRetriever; }
  //COMMON
  //private disableButton(){ this.blocked = true; }
  //COMMON
  //private activateButton(){ this.blocked = false; }

  //COMMON VARIABLE
  private userid = parseInt(this.route.parent.snapshot.params.id);

  private dataForm = new FormGroup({
    myDateRange: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  });

   constructor(
    private dataRetriever: Data,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){
  }

  ngOnInit(){


  }

  private getMonthAgo(since: Date): Date{
    var monthAgo = new Date(since.getTime());
    monthAgo.setMonth(monthAgo.getMonth() - 3);
    monthAgo.setHours(8, 0, 0, 0);
    return monthAgo;
  }

  private displayLastMonthDaysLinear(){
    var that = this;
    var yesterday = this.getYesterday();
    var monthAgo = this.getMonthAgo(yesterday);
    this.getDataRetriever().getRangeDays(this.userid, monthAgo, yesterday, function(){
      let data = that.getDataRetriever().getData();
      let labels = that.getDataRetriever().getXLabels();
      console.log(labels);
      that.linearGraph.setChart(data, labels);
    });

  }

  private displayLastWeekPie(){
    var that = this;
    var monday = this.getMondayCurrentWeek();
    var yesterday = this.getYesterday();
    if(monday.getDate() === new Date().getDate()) //If today is monday
      monday.setDate(monday.getDate()-7); //Get monday from previous week
    this.getDataRetriever().getRangeDays(this.userid, monday, yesterday, function(){
      let data = that.getDataRetriever().getData();
      let labels = that.getDataRetriever().getXLabels();
      console.log(labels);
      that.pieGraphDays.setChart(data[0].data, labels);
    });
  }

  private displayLastMonthsPie(){
    var now = new Date();
    var newYear = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0);
    var last = new Date(new Date().setMonth(now.getMonth()-1));
    var that = this;
    if(newYear.getMonth() === now.getMonth()) //If we are in January (spetial case)
      newYear.setFullYear(newYear.getFullYear() - 1); //Get January from past year
    this.getDataRetriever().getCountingPerMonth(this.userid, newYear, last, function(){
      let data = that.getDataRetriever().getData();
      let las = that.getDataRetriever().getXLabels();
      console.log(data);
      that.pieGraphMonths.setChart(data, las);
    });

  }


  private getDaysToMonth(month, year): number[] { //month not included
     var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
     var days = [];
     while (date.getMonth() < month) {
        days.push(new Date(date).setHours(8,0,0,0));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
     }
     return days;
  }

  private getYesterday(): Date{
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    today.setHours(8,0,0,0);
    return today
  }

  private getMondayCurrentWeek(): Date{
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
    d.setDate(diff);
    d.setHours(8,0,0,0);
    return d;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.displayLastMonthsPie();
    this.displayLastWeekPie();
    this.displayLastMonthDaysLinear();
    console.log(this.linearGraph);
  }

  submit(){
    let range = this.getPickedDayRange();
    var that = this;
    this.getDataRetriever().getRangeDays(this.userid, range[0], range[1], function(){
      let data = that.getDataRetriever().getData();
      let labels = that.getDataRetriever().getXLabels();
      that.pieGraphDays.setChart(data[0].data, labels);
    });
  }

  //COMMON CLASS
  private getPickedDayRange(): Date[]{
    var begDate = new Date(this.dataForm.value.myDateRange.beginJsDate);
    var endDate = new Date(this.dataForm.value.myDateRange.endJsDate);
    return [begDate, endDate];
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the component ts file

Comment: Did you import ReactiveFormsModule? It must be imported in the same component that OverviewComponent is.

Comment: Yes, it's imported into the module. Also I have another component into this module with this forms and works well

Answer (score 5):

I pieced together the answers from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783400/nested-arrays-in-angular-2-reactive-forms/42904372#42904372).

The short answer is that you have to declare the formGroup in the parent component, then pass in the formGroup to the child component.

app.component.ts

```
feedbackValues = [1,2,3,4,5];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      rowForm: this.formBuilder.group({
        rating: ['']
      })
    });
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >

  <app-survey-row [feedbackValues]=feedbackValues [parentGroup]="surveyForm"></app-survey-row>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

survey-row.component.ts

```
export class SurveyRowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() feedbackValues;
  @Input() parentGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

survey-row.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="parentGroup">
  <div formGroupName="rowForm">
    <div *ngFor="let val of feedbackValues; let i = index">
      <input id="{{i+1}}" type="radio" value="{{i+1}}" formControlName="rating">
      <label for="{{i+1}}">{{i+1}}</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the `[formGroup]` is passed in by the parent component, and the `formGroupName` is not declared in survey-row, but in app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

`dataForm` is declared as `private` in your component. What if you try to declare it as `public` (in order to make it reachable from the view)?

Comment: @SergioBarbero is the above HTML code you provide wrapped in another `<form/>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize which was the solution but finally I didn't need those formularies because the widget triggers already a function